# How to parse a XML Data within a JSON Key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xml

I have a JSON coming from Server. I am parsing JSON. I am making objects from JSON and saving into ARRAY.

```
XML PART within DATA object
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *type;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *case_description;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *case_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *type_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sender_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *data;
```

In the last variable, data, it has complete XML inside it.

I need to extract data of variable **"data"** and put inside same object's other variable which are defined above.

```
1.subtitle 
 2.type
 3.case_description
```

The XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <subtitle><![CDATA[aa]]></subtitle>
   <type>Male</type>
   <description><![CDATA[abc]]></description>
</data>
```

When I do like this.

```
-(void) findObjectAndAddInArray:(int) indexPoint{

    if (_indexPoint == [_array_cases count]-1) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableViewCase reloadData];
        });

        return;
    }
    current_case = [_array_cases objectAtIndex:indexPoint];
    NSData *data = [current_case.data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self xmlParser:data];
    _indexPoint++;

}
```

Call this method within

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

It crashes. It says, I can't call a XMLPARSER within XMLPARSER delegate method.

So, how can I modify my array or make new array which contain those objects which are inside "data" variable

Thanks.

Comment: What is the loop for? Why aren't you unpacking all the XML before you start and then finding the correct part to use?

Comment: You want me to use LOOP? For this purpose. Will loop wait for threat methods of XMLParser?